# RegEx to match full string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex for 301s that will help me identify the url: `site.com/abc/` and redirect to `site.com/xyz/`. I've tried regex as `^abc/?` and it works fine but the problem is even urls like `site.com/123/sdas/abc/213` are getting caught. How can I ensure only `/abc` gets matched with the full string url?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the end of line anchor `$`:

```
^abc/$
```

This ensures that the exact string `abc/` will be matched.

Comment: this was really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

$ matches end of string:

```
^abc/?$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 const regex = /^((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/;
      const str = `https://abc.xyz/upload/string/something/hds`;
      let m;

      if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
        m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
          console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        });
      }
```

in console:

> > Match 1 
> >     *Full match 0-43*   `https://abc.xyz/upload/string/something/hds`
> >     -Group 1.   n/a `https:/`
> >     -Group 2.   n/a `https`
> >     -Group 3.   n/a `abc.xyz`
> >     -Group 4.   n/a `/upload/string/something/`
> >     -Group 5.   n/a `/something`
> >     -Group 6.   n/a `hds`

Answer (score 0):

Write your rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ /xyz [L,NC]
```